# phpinfo () showing different values than php.ini

Tags: email, php

My `phpinfo()` shows different values than the ones I've set up in my `php.ini`, I'm on Manjaro Deepin.

**This is what `phpinfo()` shows:**

```
sendmail_from   no value    no value
sendmail_path    -t -i   -t -i 
serialize_precision 100 100
short_open_tag  On  On
SMTP    localhost   localhost
smtp_port   25  25
```

**This is what the `php.ini` file looks like:**

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 587
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = exchange_shop@uniwa.gr
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: It says those are for windows 32, i dont know what Manjaro Deepin is, but im guessing very much not win32?

Comment: smtp_port is not for win32 and it's still the wrong value as is sendmail_path

Comment: Well as the ini file lists 587 and its picking up 25........

Comment: I found it I'm using LAMPP and it has a different php.ini file. That was all, thanks for the interest in the question :D

Comment: ah, the full output from php -i or phpinfo() should have shown the path